# How to overload operator< for object oriented hierarchy?

Tags: c++, object, polymorphism, overloading, oop

I have the following classes

```
class A{
    operator<(A & object);  //how do i make it so hat B < C?
};

class B: public A{
    operator<(A & object);
};

class C: public A {
    operator<(A & object);
};
A * ptr = new B();
A * ptr2 = new C();

if (*ptr < *ptr2)   //how do I overload this?
```

How can I overload the < function so that it know class B is smaller than class C?

Comment: A good start may be to make the function virtual.

Comment: Is the logic different on the derived classes?

Comment: Yes. But it will says B is < C right away. The logic in the derived classes are only needed if the 2 objects are of the same derived classes like B vs B

Comment: This is [double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), which is hard.  I'd recommend changing your code to avoid this where possible.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Like Mooing Duck said, when you need to dyanmically bind two objects at runtime you need to use double dispatch. In this case we can do it simple cause there are few types involved.

Start by making the call virtual:

```
class B;
class C;

class A{
public:
    virtual bool operator<(const A & object) const = 0; // I assume you only care about B and C
    virtual bool operator<(const B & object) const = 0;
    virtual bool operator<(const C & object) const = 0;
};
```

Then do something like this:

```
class B: public A{
public:
    virtual bool operator<(const A & object) const
    {
        // do a second bind, now that we know 'this' is type B. Negate cause we
        // are switching the operands.
        return !object.operator<( (const B&)*this);
    }
    virtual bool operator<(const B & object) const
    {
        //<do your logic>; // here you can assume both will be type B
    }
    virtual bool operator<(const C & object) const
    {
        return true; // B is always < than C right?
    }
};

class C: public A{
public:
    virtual bool operator<(const A & object) const
    {
        // do a second bind, now that we know 'this' is type C. Negate cause we
        // are switching the operands.
        return !object.operator<( (const C&)*this);
    }
    virtual bool operator<(const B & object) const
    {
        return false; // C is always > then B right?
    }
    virtual bool operator<(const C & object) const
    {
        //<do your logic>; // here you can assume both will be type C
    }
};
```

What we do here do a dynamic binding for each object, thus knowing both types at runtime.

UPDATE:
I changed the code a bit to prevent infinite recursion.

Comment: While thinking about this question I already tried this.  [Stack overflow due to infinite recursion](http://ideone.com/LgFlvJ).  When A has to have overloads for `const B& object` and `const C& object` however: [it works](http://ideone.com/mwV0wh)

Comment: @MooingDuck, you're totally right, I updated the answer, thank you.